# Removing collection items without a ConcurrentModificationException using nested Iterators

Tags: java, android, concurrentmodification

I'm enduring this exception and after reading around I understand you can usually deal with it by using an Iterator. But having tried that I find it doesn't work in this scenario, perhaps because I have two nested loops? All the code is running on the main thread (Android).

```
 private boolean removeRoutesWithTimestampFromTeams(long time) {
    boolean routesRemoved = false;
    Iterator<WhizzyTeam> teamIterator = assignedTeams.iterator();
    while (teamIterator.hasNext()) {
        WhizzyTeam team = teamIterator.next();  // EXCEPTION HERE
        Iterator<Route> routeIterator = team.routes.iterator();
        while (teamIterator.hasNext()) {
            Route route = routeIterator.next();
            if (route.whizzy_assignment_time_in_millis == time) {
                team.removeRoute(route);
                routesRemoved = true;
            }
        }
        if (team.routes == null || team.routes.size() == 0) {
            assignedTeams.remove(team);
            unassignedTeams.add(team);
        }
    }
    return routesRemoved;
```

I'm relying on object references to identify objects, so copying collections is a very unattractive option. Is there any way to do what I need to do without resorting to copies?

===== WORKING CODE =====

I actually made three mistakes that are fixed here.
1. I used the same iterator in both loops (fixed in the code above too)
2. I should have used Iterator.remove()
3. Within removeRoute() there was another (unnecessary) for loop looping through routes to delete similar siblings

```
private boolean removeRoutesWithTimestampFromTeams(long time) {
    boolean routesRemoved = false;
    Iterator<WhizzyTeam> teamIterator = assignedTeams.iterator();
    while (teamIterator.hasNext()) {
        WhizzyTeam team = teamIterator.next();
        Iterator<Route> routeIterator = team.routes.iterator();
        while (routeIterator.hasNext()) {
            Route route = routeIterator.next();
            if (route.whizzy_assignment_time_in_millis == time) {
                routeIterator.remove();
                routesRemoved = true;
            }
        }
        if (team.routes == null || team.routes.size() == 0) {
            teamIterator.remove();
            unassignedTeams.add(team);
        }
    }
    return routesRemoved;
}
```

Comment: you are using two times `teamIterator`, in the first and in the second loop, and you should use the iterator itself to remove the object from  the collection

Comment: Did you try calling Iterators `remove()` method?

Comment: @OllieC assignedTeams and team.routes are list???

Comment: @Blackbelt You are dead right there. I changed the inner loop to use the correct iterator, but I am still seeing the same exception, but in the first call to next().

Comment: @SivaKumar Yes, they are both ArrayList types.

Comment: did you try with iterator.remove() ?

Comment: Why are you using `team.removeRoute(route);` instead of `routeIterator.remove(route)`?

Comment: @Blackbelt Your answer led me to the solution. If you want to re-post your comment as an answer I will accept it. The problem was two fold. Firstly I was using the wrong iterator in the inner loop. Secondly I was not using remove() on the iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with the snippet you posted. The first one you are using the *outer* iterator also int inner loop

```
  while (teamIterator.hasNext()) {
        WhizzyTeam team = teamIterator.next();  // EXCEPTION HERE
        Iterator<Route> routeIterator = team.routes.iterator();
        while (teamIterator.hasNext()) {
```

I do think you should use `routeIterator`, in place of `teamIterator` in the second loop.

Second you are not using the remove method from the Iterator interface to remove the item from your collection. From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As you can tell, using nested iterators can lead to mixups in using the wrong one, etc. Another approach to doing this without iterators is to keep track of the ones you want to remove while iterating, then remove them after. This approach does require temporary collections, but allows you to use the foreach loop and prevent errors with using the wrong iterators.

```
private boolean removeRoutesWithTimestampFromTeams(long time) {
    boolean routesRemoved = false;
    List<WhizzyTeam> teamsToUnassign = new ArrayList<>();
    for( WhizzyTeam team : assignedTeams ) {
        List<Route> routesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
        for( Route route : team.routes ) {
            if (route.whizzy_assignment_time_in_millis == time) {
                routesToRemove.add( route );
            }
        }
        if( routesToRemove.size() > 0 ) {
            team.routes.removeAll( routesToRemove );
            if( team.routes.isEmpty() ) {
                teamsToUnassign.add( team );
            }
            routesRemoved = true;
        }
    }
    assignedTeams.removeAll( teamsToUnassign );
    unassignedTeams.addAll( teamsToUnassign );

    return routesRemoved;
}
```